# RegEx para capturar números únicos dentro de uma string

Tags: regex

Estou tentando criar um RegEx que captura apenas números únicos no meio de outros caracteres (desde que sigam a condição de não serem seguidos por outros números).

**Exemplos:**

```
"R3g3x": ["3","3"]
"J4v4scr1pt": ["4","4","1"]
"1nício": ["1"]
"Fina1": ["1"]
"Dup10": []
```

Por enquanto o que eu consegui foi capturar os números dentro das palavras, mas meu RegEx ainda não restringe a sequência por outro número.

Está assim: `\d+(?=\w)(?!\d)`

Alguém faz ideia de como devo proceder?

Comment: Apenas para tirar uma dúvida, seu último exemplo não deveria ser: `"Dup10": [0]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\d+` captura um ou mais dígitos (`+` é um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências"), então se a string for `abc10xyz`, ele vai capturar o `10`. Se a ideia é capturar apenas um único dígito, retire o `+`.

De qualquer forma, pelo que entendi você quer um dígito desde que não tenha outro dígito antes nem depois. Sendo assim, você pode usar [*lookahead* e *lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) negativos:

```
(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)
```

Assim ele só pega dígitos isolados, que não tenham outro dígito antes e nem depois (ou seja, o dígito também pode estar no início ou fim da string). E se tiver dois ou mais dígitos seguidos (como o caso de "Dup10"), ele não pega nenhum (se você usar `\d+`, o "10" de "Dup10" será capturado).

---

Ao usar o [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\w)`, a regex está exigindo que exista algum caractere à frente (letras, números ou `_`), portanto não funciona se o número estiver no final da string, ou se o caractere que aparece depois não for equivalente a `\w`. Mas como estou usando *lookahead* e *lookbehind* negativos (ou seja, verifica se algo **não** existe à frente ou atrás), isso também serve para dígitos no início ou no final (pois se o dígito está no início, então não tem um dígito antes, e se está no final, não tem um dígito depois).

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/RNuRjw/1/) a regex funcionando.

---

Se você só quer os dígitos que não tenham outro dígito depois, então basta retirar o *lookbehind*:

```
\d(?!\d)
```

Mas neste caso, em "Dup10", a regex dará *match* no `0`.

---

Se a *engine* não suportar *lookbehind* (já que este *geralmente* possui menos suporte que *lookahead*), uma alternativa é verificar se o dígito está no início da string (com o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`) ou se antes dele tem um caractere que não é dígito (`\D`):

```
(?:^|\D)(\d)(?!\d)
```

Eu uso [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou") para verificar o início da string (`^`) ou um caractere que não é dígito (`\D`). Só que agora o caractere que vem antes do dígito também faz parte do *match*. Mas como o dígito está entre parênteses, ele está em um grupo de captura, então verifique se a ferramenta/*engine* possui uma maneira de pegar somente o grupo.

Como só há um par de parênteses (`(\d)`), ele será o grupo 1 ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/RNuRjw/3/), no lado direito em *Match Information* aparece o conteúdo do "Group 1").

O `(?:` cria um grupo de não-captura (ou seja, este par de parênteses não cria um grupo).

E se a *engine* também não suportar *lookahead*, você pode usar uma [ideia similar](https://regex101.com/r/RNuRjw/5/): verificar se o que tem depois é `\D` ou o final da string (`$`):

```
(?:^|\D)(\d)(?:\D|$)
```

Só que agora tanto o caractere que estiver antes quanto o que estiver depois farão parte do *match*, então você precisa acessar o grupo de captura para pegar somente o dígito.

---

Outra opção (que também pode não ser suportada em todas as *engines*) é o [atalho `\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html):

```
(?:^|\D)\K\d(?!\d)
```

O que ele faz é descartar tudo que foi encontrado até então (no caso, o início da string ou o caractere que não é dígito), então somente o `\d` fará parte do *match*.

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Aparentemente a ferramenta que estou usando não aceita nenhum tipo de lookbehind. Existe alguma outra técnica que tenha o mesmo resultado (sem nenhum match para "Dup10")?

Comment: @ZecaNovaes Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Boa! Testei aqui e foi. Obrigado mais uma vez, me salvou muito!